# Need help with applescript and wolfram alpha interface

Tags: applescript

Okay so here's my code... My question is, can I determine what type of data it is before grabbing the text, because if I search something like "how many tablespoons in an ounce, it just gives me a bunch of useless code and doesn't grab the right text. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
    tell application "Safari"
    quit
end tell

set defaultAnswer to ""
set cancelButton to "Cancel"
set buttonResearch to "ReSearch"

display dialog "Query: " default answer defaultAnswer buttons {cancelButton, buttonResearch} default button buttonResearch cancel button cancelButton with icon 1
copy the result as list to {button_pressed, text_returned}

tell application "Dragon Dictate"
    set listening to false
end tell


if (button_pressed is buttonResearch) and (text_returned is not "") then
    set a to "http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i="
    set b to encode_text(text_returned, true, false)
    set c to a & b

    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        open
    end tell
    repeat
        if application "Safari" is running then exit repeat
    end repeat
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "m" using command down
    end tell
    tell application "Safari"
        tell window 1
            set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:c})
        end tell
    end tell
end if

say "let me look that up for you now"
delay 6

tell application "Safari" to set theString to (source of document 1)

(* Strip the text and only return the last line*)
set input to do shell script "echo " & (quoted form of theString) & "|sed -n \"/stringified/,/mInput/p\" | sed '$!N;$!D'"



global answer

set offSet1 to "\"stringified\": \""
set offSet2 to "\",\"mInput\""


my strip(offSet1, offSet2, input)

set mywordcount to count of words of answer

if mywordcount is greater than 50 then
    display dialog x
else


end if

tell application "Safari"
    quit
end tell

tell application "Dragon Dictate"
    set listening to true
end tell

on strip(offSet1, offSet2, thedata)
    (* Use the offsets of the pattens to match the text # thru # *)
    set textNumber1 to (offset of offSet1 in thedata)
    set theData1 to text -1 thru (textNumber1 + (count of offSet1)) of thedata
    set textNumber2 to (offset of offSet2 in theData1)
    set textString2 to text from word 1 to (textNumber2 - 1) of theData1
    set thedata to theData1
    set answer to textString2
end strip

-- encoding high-ASCII characters:
on encode_char(this_char)
    set the ASCII_num to (the ASCII number this_char)
    set the hex_list to {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}
    set x to item ((ASCII_num div 16) + 1) of the hex_list
    set y to item ((ASCII_num mod 16) + 1) of the hex_list
    return ("%" & x & y) as string
end encode_char

-- TEXT ENCODING: encode spaces and high-level ASCII characters (those above 127)
-- encode_URL_A = encode most of the special characters reserved for use by URLs.
on encode_text(this_text, encode_URL_A, encode_URL_B)
    set the standard_characters to "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    set the URL_A_chars to "$+!'/?;&@=#%><{}[]\"~`^\\|*"
    set the URL_B_chars to ".-_:"
    set the acceptable_characters to the standard_characters
    if encode_URL_A is false then set the acceptable_characters to the acceptable_characters & the URL_A_chars
    if encode_URL_B is false then set the acceptable_characters to the acceptable_characters & the URL_B_chars
    set the encoded_text to ""
    repeat with this_char in this_text
        if this_char is in the acceptable_characters then
            set the encoded_text to (the encoded_text & this_char)
        else
            set the encoded_text to (the encoded_text & encode_char(this_char)) as string
        end if
    end repeat
    return the encoded_text
end encode_text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the section's name to click on the "Copyable plaintext" button :

- first section = **pod_0100**, second section = **pod_0200**,  third
     section = **pod_0300**

Use the button's index :

- `('action subpod-copyablept ')[0]` = the first "Copyable plaintext" button in a section.
- `('action subpod-copyablept ')[1]` = the second "Copyable plaintext" button in a section.

The answer of the popup window is appended to the end of the document.

EX ( query : "**how many tablespoons in an ounce**"):

- if the script click on the first Copyable button in 'pod_0200' section, the
  script return "**2 tbsp  (tablespoons)**"
- if the script click on the first Copyable button in 'pod_0100' section, the
  script return "**convert 1 fl oz  (fluid ounce) to tablespoons**"

--

```
if (button_pressed is buttonResearch) and (text_returned is not "") then
    set theUrl to "http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=" & encode_text(text_returned, true, false)
    tell application "Safari"
        tell window 1 to set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:theUrl})
        tell me to say "let me look that up for you now"
        tell document 1
            repeat -- wait until loaded
                delay 2
                if (do JavaScript "document.readyState") = "complete" then exit repeat
            end repeat
            do JavaScript "document.getElementById('pod_0200').getElementsByClassName('action subpod-copyablept ')[0].click()" -- show the popup window
            set theAnswer to do JavaScript "document.body.lastChild.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML;" -- get the answer in this popup window
        end tell
    end tell
    activate
    display dialog theAnswer
end if
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! You are awesome! This is only my second week working with applescript so i'm really new to all the codes. Thanks again you really saved me on this one!